# How to use `process.client` using TypeScript with Nuxt.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
if (process.client) {
    // do something
}
```

Getting error `Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i @types/node.`

`@types/node` is installed.

It seems to be a recurrent error as other people have reported the bug on Github (ie. https://github.com/nuxt-community/typescript-template/issues/33). No one seems to have found a clean solution that works as of now.

Anyone has an idea or managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nuxt 2.10 or above you can take a look at more recent [Nuxt official TypeScript support](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup.html) if you haven't done so. I created a new 2.11 Nuxt project, followed their instructions to setup and process.client works fine for me.

Comment: It's what I've done too. My app works, but I get that error / warning message when that specific file is open in my editor.

Comment: Does it only happen in one specific file (i.e. only inside your component lifecycle hooks and not inside plugins) ? I'm using vscode btw and usually fix these kind of typescript issues by _Ctrl+Shift+P_ and _Reload Window_ in vscode. Maybe you can also try reinstalling your app dependencies.